# Use inline block on 2 elements inside a component in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a component with two elements passed to it. I want the two elements to be displayed side by side. I've tried to use display: inline-block in CSS but it won't actually put the two elements side by side. I want the elements to be the same size so each of them will take up 50% of the screen.

I am finding react a bit tricky to style with CSS. Any advice how to make this work?
This is my component.

```
class Dashboardbox extends React.Component {
render(){
    return(
        <div className="dashboardbox">
         <Coursebox />
         <Newsbox />
        </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render( < Dashboardbox />, document.getElementById('dashboardbox'));
```

and my CSS

```
.course {
background-color: lightgrey;
margin-left: 20px;
height: 80%;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family: arial;
padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.dashboard {
display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: Where are those css classes being used? Do you have a css rules for dashboardbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/mybceqe9/) what you wanted

The important part:

```
.box-field {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}


class Coursebox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className='box-field'> Course box </div>
  }
}

class Newsbox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className='box-field'> News box </div>
  }
}
```

You don't need to style dashboardbox.

Comment: The Coursebox has several elements in it and I want there to be spacing between each element but now it's all treated as one div. Any idea how I can keep the seperation between each element and still use this?